# Конкатенация PHP + HTML

Tags: php

Очень странно всё получилось, написал систему категорий, кучу раз используя конкатенацию. Понял что система бесполезна, удалил, решил писать заново. Начал только писать и тут же у IDE возник вопрос - "ты чо дурак? что ты пишешь вообще?". Кароче код:

```
<?php
echo '<div class="hello">' . <?php $data['category'] ?> . '</div>';
?>
```

Почему-то открывающий `<?php`в самом начале кода считает что `?>` после `$data['category']` - его закрывающий собрат. Над сайтом просидел 15 часов, прочитал весь форум, четыре статьи, много раз переписывал, обращался к гуглу. Голова совсем не хочет работать :( В чём ошибка? Я блин, не вижу :ССС

Текст ошибки:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?>' in
>   D:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\localhost\index.php on line 159

P.S.: Она указывает именно на эту строку. Ни на какую больше (другие без ошибок и не участвуют в процессе)

Comment: Смотрите на ваш код `<?php ... <?php ... ?> ... >?`. Вам не кажется бессмысленным указывать тег php внутри тега php? Это не фильм "Начало", это php. Признайте, что программирование не для вас

Comment: Я не заметил этого потому что кроме echo там достаточно объемный код. Вырезал только часть, ибо все остальное к ошибке не относится. А когда писал вопрос об этом не думал) Самая простая синтаксическая ошибка которая обоснована моей невнимательностью. Тоже самое что поставить лишний символ. Спасибо конечно, но ваш вывод в конце не аргументирован.

Comment: Перепишите ответ из комментариев и я поставлю вам плюсик

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант(Вы попытались отрыть php в уже отрытом теге php "`<?php`", соответственно получили ошибку):

```
<div class="hello"><?= $data['category'] ?></div>
```

или

```
<?php echo '<div class="hello">' . $data['category'] . '</div>'; ?>
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Answer (score 0):

Ты неправильно сделал.

```
<?php
echo '<div class="hello">' .$data['category']. '</div>';
?>
```

Вот так работать будет.